# Access is denied (fle not found Exception)

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I'm tring to save a file in to a path that I obtain with JfileChooser, but when I save in this path it throws :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Documents (Access is denied)
```

This is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(testoNumeroIntervalli,new Integer(singletonAutomobilista.getNumeroIntervalli()));
        try{

            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(percorso);
            file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: run as administrator .can u manually open it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the path is not open to the user in question. Try to save it somewhere accessible with this user such as a new directory under "c:/documents/".